# Jackson annotation of deserialize Object property into JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson

This is a java model class used for calling REST API. The type of the property "value" is Object because the json is nested.

```
public class request {
    public String id;
    public Object value;
}
```

In unit test, i want to deserialize the property "value" as "JsonNode".

How to annotate the class without a custom deserializer?

Answer (score 1):

For deserializing the "value" property as a JsonNode without using a custom deserializer, you can utilize Jackson's @JsonRawValue annotation. This annotation allows you to indicate that the property should be serialized and deserialized as a raw JSON value.

You can modify your request class like this:

```
public class Request {
    public String id;

    @JsonRawValue
    public Object value;
}
```

Comment: Will @JsonRawValue breaks serialization?  If the value is String, then special characters will not be escaped.

Comment: If the value is a String and contains special characters, using @JsonRawValue may lead to issues because special characters won't be automatically escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround: provide a setter method to jackson

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Request {
    
    private String id;
    private Object value;
    
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public void setJsonNodeToValue(JsonNode n) {
        value = n;
    }
    
}
```